# C# Creating a generic task without starting it

Tags: generics, asynchronous, async-await, expression-trees, fluent

SHORT VERSION: I would like to create a *GENERIC* task that can be executed later, but I'm not sure of the syntax needed to do so.

LONG VERSION: I've built a custom Fluent syntax SQL Generator/ORM. It includes synchronous methods like...

```
var dt = DB.Select().From("TABLE_NAME").Where("WHERE CONDITIONS").ToDataTable(connString);
var dr = DB.Select().From("TABLE_NAME").Where("WHERE CONDITIONS").ToDataReader(connString);
```

that return a System.Data.DataTable/DataReader (old school, but I still have lots of legacy ADO.NET code to deal with).

I am now introducing async/await and Tasks to this generator.  I want to create something like

```
var task1 = DB.Select().From("TABLE_NAME").Where("WHERE CONDITIONS").ToTask<DataTable>(connString);
var task2 = DB.Select().From("TABLE_NAME").Where("WHERE CONDITIONS").ToTask<DataRow>(connString);
var task3 = DB.Select().From("TABLE_NAME").Where("WHERE CONDITIONS").ToTask<DataReader>(connString);
```

Each task brings back a *potentially* different generic type.  But I want delayed execution.  I want to potentially bring back many tasks and then do a...

```
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, etc...)
```

**I am struggling on how to code that...here's my thoughts so far...**

```
public Task<T> ToTask<T>(string connStr)
{
     Task<T> t = new Task<T>();  //maybe?

     //SetResult will block until loaded???
     TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
     tcs.SetResult((T) LoadThisGenericType(typeof(T)));
     return tcs.Task;
}
```

Am I biting off more than I can chew?? Any guidance would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**  Here is my implementation of ToDataReaderAsync for reference purposes...

```
public async Task<SqlDataReader> ToDataReaderAsync(string connStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = await DB.SQL.CreateConnectionAsync(connStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = DB.SQL.CreateCommand(con))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "TEXT OF COMMAND HERE"; //Stored proc, INSERT, UPDATE, etc...
            return await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        }
}
```

Comment: You could use some type of synchronization objects (similar to mutex or semaphore), that the created tasks would wait for until the main thread signaled those objects.

Comment: Post an example synchronous implementation (e.g., `ToDataReader`), and then it should be clear how to create the asynchronous equivalent (e.g., `ToDataReaderAsync`).

Comment: @StephenCleary I've updated the post to include my implementation of ToDataReaderAsync.  That part is easy.  What I can't figure out is the generic ToTask<T> implementation.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're *trying* to do with a generic `ToTask` implementation. What value does it provide?

Comment: @StephenCleary I really want Deferred parallel execution.  Instead of returning a DataReader, I want to return a Task<DataReader> that is going to execute later.  Or a Task<DataTable>, or Task<DateRow>, etc..  I see a lot of Task.WhenAll examples and I'm trying to position my code to take advantage of that (but in a GENERIC way).

Comment: I'm now wondering if I shouldn't use a generic constraint so that I can minimize the potential generic types to just DataTable, DataRow, DataReader  like 
public Task<T> ToTask<T>(string connStr) : where T : DataReader

Comment: Generics in .NET are not meant to do metaprogramming. E.g., constraints don't participate in overload resolution. You already have methods that return `Task<DataReader>` etc. If you want to delay execution, return a `Func<Task<DataReader>>` (or an expression equivalent).

Comment: Your `ToDataReaderAsync` method already returning `Task<SqlDataReader>` so you can await it whenever you want. Another not related notice: `SqlDataReader` needs opened connection for reading data. After `return await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();` line connection will be closed and any consumer of `ToDataReaderAsync` method will end up with "broken" datareader.